# Extracting Data from a HTTP log file for a Specific string

Tags: search, text, full-text-search

Hi what I want to do is capture the web site details from a log file (see example below), only the data between the `url= and the /` is required.

The Text that I want will appear like :- url=http://rewards.ebay.com.au/
This will come from a file downloaded to the local computer.

So far my Linux skills have failed me, as there are very rusty.

```
2016:10:07-09:22:08 remote httpproxy[5492]: id="0001" severity="info" sys="SecureWeb" sub="http" name="http access" action="pass" method="GET" srcip="172.20.47.77" dstip="66.135.210.162" user="" group="" ad_domain="" statuscode="200" cached="0" profile="REF_DefaultHTTPProfile (Default Web Filter Profile)" filteraction="REF_DefaultHTTPCFFAction (Default content filter action)" size="528" request="0x176b8c00" url="http://rewards.ebay.com.au/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?GetRewardsInfo&item=112156322448&ShowCoupon=true&ShowVoucher=false&IsBidFlow=true&IsViewItem=true&item=112156322448&cguid=97fac6cc1530a629a7c13ed1f7ab0909&cb=jQuery17035599369188600694_1475803327599&_=1475803328055" referer="http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/1-6-SCALE-dragon-WW2-GERMAN-SS-OFFICERS-WHITE-PIPS-AND-DECORATIONS/112156322448?_trksid=p2060778.c100276.m3476&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20140813105702%26meid%3D29ba022992ea4bd783400dd10e50825f%26pid%3D100276%26rk%3D3%26rkt%3D4%26sd%3D112152394027" error="" authtime="0" dnstime="108071" cattime="261877" avscantime="0" fullreqtime="1123523" device="1" auth="0" ua="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36" exceptions="" category="158" reputation="trusted" categoryname="Auctions/Classifieds" content-type="application/json" application="ebay" app-id="134"
2016:10:07-09:22:09 remote httpproxy[5492]: id="0001" severity="info" sys="SecureWeb" sub="http" name="http access" action="pass" method="GET" srcip="172.20.47.77" dstip="66.135.211.38" user="" group="" ad_domain="" statuscode="200" cached="0" profile="REF_DefaultHTTPProfile (Default Web Filter Profile)" filteraction="REF_DefaultHTTPCFFAction (Default content filter action)" size="5242" request="0x174b3800" url="http://srx.au.ebayrtm.com/rtm?RtmCmd&a=json&i=3Fw8hYwlfJGMGXyhg&g=97fabafb1530a63a3093c5c8ffd648ea&uf=1&c=1H4sIAAAAAAAAAFVSTW%2FiMBC98ytGWqmHVUo8Y8d2kKwqgtAibQIiqbhwIRBBqkIiSBalv35tsrtST%2FPxxm9m3vhHfupguW%2BBSUA9IZqwAF6T%2FJmpCWNADOWo4UwbMWqEIMNGDYbCEFmHGQy0VKFLocn7pvSifVvVF5hXx%2B5aeln1VXpI1WXsJavUm9XlDdK6hahpPvtRQ1oZJEKhSGDIAw%2BRMKBQSC20ZzlVwEhqjczjEimQTAZSCI80oUKulQVtb6VNXvc3D97qoqjK27ZjjOG3Sf7mkuqzanfXHp4gOvwuL62FBsTRBP%2FW2VcHO9cAIPtfIISxhqNyhqwkGFjLpUnLu3WkeohDQ1pKEyobokE2Zq5OmGf3LnRtJAtEyB2L1dCXkE2" referer="http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/1-6-SCALE-dragon-WW2-GERMAN-SS-OFFICERS-WHITE-PIPS-AND-DECORATIONS/112156322448?_trksid=p2060778.c100276.m3476&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20140813105702%26meid%3D29ba022992ea4bd783400dd10e50825f%26pid%3D100276%26rk%3D3%26rkt%3D4%26sd%3D112152394027" error="" authtime="0" dnstime="106880" cattime="271" avscantime="0" fullreqtime="1160152" device="1" auth="0" ua="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36" exceptions="" category="158" reputation="neutral" categoryname="Auctions/Classifieds" content-type="application/x-javascript" application="ebay" app-id="134"
2016:10:07-09:22:09 remote httpproxy[5492]: id="0001" severity="info" sys="SecureWeb" sub="http" name="http access" action="pass" method="CONNECT" srcip="172.20.47.77" dstip="106.10.198.33" user="" group="" ad_domain="" statuscode="200" cached="0" profile="REF_DefaultHTTPProfile (Default Web Filter Profile)" filteraction="REF_DefaultHTTPCFFAction (Default content filter action)" size="4248" request="0xae92c00" url="https://ads.yahoo.com/" referer="" error="" authtime="0" dnstime="8" cattime="228" avscantime="0" fullreqtime="80037102" device="1" auth="0" ua="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36" exceptions="" category="154" reputation="trusted" categoryname="Web Ads" application="yahoo" app-id="553"
2016:10:07-09:22:09 remote httpproxy[5492]: id="0001" severity="info" sys="SecureWeb" sub="http" name="http access" action="pass" method="CONNECT" srcip="172.20.47.77" dstip="172.217.25.161" user="" group="" ad_domain="" statuscode="200" cached="0" profile="REF_DefaultHTTPProfile (Default Web Filter Profile)" filteraction="REF_DefaultHTTPCFFAction (Default content filter action)" size="4631" request="0x16e8ea00" url="https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/" referer="" error="" authtime="0" dnstime="583136" cattime="241475" avscantime="0" fullreqtime="86706443" device="1" auth="0" ua="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36" exceptions="" category="145" reputation="neutral" categoryname="Search Engines" application="googads" app-id="815"
2016:10:07-09:22:09 remote httpproxy[5492]: id="0001" severity="info" sys="SecureWeb" sub="http" name="http access" action="pass" method="CONNECT" srcip="172.20.47.77" dstip="172.217.25.161" user="" group="" ad_domain="" statuscode="200" cached="0" profile="REF_DefaultHTTPProfile (Default Web Filter Profile)" filteraction="REF_DefaultHTTPCFFAction (Default content filter action)" size="4631" request="0x18e4d600" url="https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/" referer="" error="" authtime="0" dnstime="583291" cattime="244652" avscantime="0" fullreqtime="86710584" device="1" auth="0" ua="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36" exceptions="" category="145" reputation="neutral" categoryname="Search Engines" application="googads" app-id="815"
2016:10:07-09:22:09 remote httpproxy[5492]: id="0001" severity="info" sys="SecureWeb" sub="http" name="http access" action="pass" method="CONNECT" srcip="172.20.47.77" dstip="172.217.25.161" user="" group="" ad_domain="" statuscode="200" cached="0" profile="REF_DefaultHTTPProfile (Default Web Filter Profile)" filteraction="REF_DefaultHTTPCFFAction (Default content filter action)" size="4631" request="0xa209600" url="https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/" referer="" error="" authtime="0" dnstime="583533" cattime="243934" avscantime="0" fullreqtime="86711519" device="1" auth="0" ua="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36" exceptions="" category="145" reputation="neutral" categoryname="Search Engines" application="googads" app-id="815"
2016:10:07-09:22:09 remote httpproxy[5492]: id="0001" severity="info" sys="SecureWeb" sub="http" name="http access" action="pass" method="GET" srcip="172.20.47.77" dstip="50.97.236.98" user="" group="" ad_domain="" statuscode="200" cached="0" profile="REF_DefaultHTTPProfile (Default Web Filter Profile)" filteraction="REF_DefaultHTTPCFFAction (Default content filter action)" size="957" request="0x16fa4c00" url="http://tags.bluekai.com/site/20267?ret=html&limit=4&btp=1&phint=eid%3D1650&phint=tcat%3D220&phint=crm%3D4&phint=cg%3D97fac6cc1530a629a7c13ed1f7ab0909&phint=btf%3D&phint=btp%3D:a:b:c:d:e&phint=gid%3D1&phint=inid%3D-99&phint=css%3D34&phint=c%3D0&phint=m%3DN&phint=aid%3Dtf&phint=ps%3D1&phint=fm_segment%3D15:12,15:12&phint=pageid%3D2047675&phint=referrer%3Dwww.ebay.com.au&phint=user_type%3D22&phint=symphony%3D0" referer="http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/1-6-SCALE-dragon-WW2-GERMAN-SS-OFFICERS-WHITE-PIPS-AND-DECORATIONS/112156322448?_trksid=p2060778.c100276.m3476&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20140813105702%26meid%3D29ba022992ea4bd783400dd10e50825f%26pid%3D100276%26rk%3D3%26rkt%3D4%26sd%3D112152394027" error="" authtime="0" dnstime="828" cattime="26036" avscantime="0" fullreqtime="647201" device="1" auth="0" ua="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36" exceptions="" category="105" reputation="neutral" categoryname="Business" content-type="text/html" application="ebay" app-id="134"
```

Comment: Can you please format it?

Comment: Hi ManetsusI'm not sure

Comment: Actually I told about formatting the text of the question. Sorry for using shortcut.

Comment: Hi Manetsus, I'm not sure what you mean by "format it". Each row of text appears like above as a new line, with the text that I'm interested about 3/4 in. (Please excuse my mi- understanding as I have had a major brain injury due to a car accident which affects my language center). Mark